# How to address-bar align left in html5

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have created one web page using html5,css and js.

After i designed logo,search box and menu I added address at the top of header.

Here is html and css code:

Html:

```
<div id="address">255 White Street, Danbury CT 06810 | 203.730.1776 | <a href="mailto:info@tksamericancafe.com" class="white">info@tksamericancafe.com</a></div>
```

css:

```
#address {
width: 600px;
float: right;
display: inline;
font-size: 13px;
color: #FFF;
margin-top: 2px;
}
#address a 
{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Here is my web page look like this: http://s30.postimg.org/yrays8nfl/Untitled_1_copy.png

search box, menu bar all others are same margin, the address bar is not correct margin-align.

I need to display address bar as `float: right;`, i added but there is something not proper in float-right.

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!..

Comment: There should be quotation marks around the ID in the HTML

Comment: but its worked without quotation marks..

Comment: There **should** be quotation marks around the ID in the HTML. It may work but it's malformed, that's browsers being nice to you.

Comment: but its working without quotation marks, how?

Comment: The browser is filling in the quotation marks for you. Don't rely on all browsers being so thoughtful.

Comment: Safari isnt so unforgiven as firefox. Chrome is on other points unforgiven. You always want to double check your code.

Comment: okay okay... I have created simple web page using html5 and css and js. I have an one doubt, that is. for example when click register link, it will show register page right?.. so that i have created register page with validation using php. Now what my question is, How to design that register page looks like index page design?

Comment: @Dorvalla: okay okay... I have created simple web page using html5 and css and js. I have an one doubt, that is. for example when click register link, it will show register page right?.. so that i have created register page with validation using php. Now what my question is, How to design that register page looks like index page design?.. and may i know, how to split header footer and content for reusing ?

Comment: Well, for one, i make use of includes to do this. I write my own header and footer, put them in a seperate file, and I include them on everypage while the rest is loaded dynamicly. Then again, i use PHP to do this. However, you can also do this with javascript if you dont want to use server side languages: http://webdesign.about.com/od/javascript/ht/htjsincludehtm.htm is a good start

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in :

```
#address {
    text-align:right;
}
```

To your CSS this will push the text to the right of the container.